# Javascript - Can there be 3 or more '===' in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword

So, for example, will

```
function myFunction() {
    if(var_1 === var_2 === var_3 === var_4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

return true or false when

```
var_1 = true;
var_2 = true;
var_3 = true;
var_4 = true;
```

Also, what will the function 'myFunction' return when

```
var_1 = false;
var_2 = false;
var_3 = false;
var_4 = false;
```

and

```
var_1 = "abc";
var_2 = "abc";
var_3 = "abc";
var_4 = "abc";
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens when you try any of these things? It seems to me that a quick test of your own could provide an answer to all of these questions.

Comment: Yes .. but it won't do what you expect in most cases: `a === b === c` is equivalent to `(a === b) === c`, where `===` evaluates to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @user2864740: The associativity goes the other way.

Comment: If I recall, Python behaves as expected, but for most languages, including Javascript, this won't work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the first `===` will equate to `true` (or `false`) and will not equal the next variable.

So `var_1 === var_2` will either be `true` or `false`.

It then compares that result to `var_3` like this `true/false === var_3`. That gives a result of true or false. That second result is then compared to `var_4`.

So this will be `true` according to your test:

```
var_1 = "yes";
var_2 = "apple";
var_3 = "amazing";
var_4 = false;
```

I presume that's not what you want :)

Comment: Bump. Caught up with you in reputation :D

Comment: @chris97ong Good on you, Chris. You'll go much further than I have :)

Answer (score 2):

The case with three variables will be easier to work with. It'll be interpreted as:

```
(a == b) == c
```

Which will be:

```
(some boolean) == c
```

That's probably not what you intend to happen. To work around this, use the transitivity of equality:

```
(a == b) && (b == c)
```

Comment: "transitivity of equality" - groovy :)

Answer (score -1):

In all 3 condition the function will return true..

yes there can be  3 '===' in a single statement